# Vertically center two divs in a div

Tags: css, html, vertical-alignment

I tried a lot of solutions but nothing is working. I have a div with variable height which contains three other divs side-by-side. That works great.

Now I want that two of the three divs (left and middle one) to be vertically centered. But it won't work. I tried it with the line-height (works for pictures) but the line-height has to be the same height as the window.

Here's my html:

```
<div id="outerDiv">
    <div id="LeftDiv">
        <img id="imgArrow" src="images/arrow.png">
    </div>
    <div id="middleDiv">
         <div id="buttonDiv" class="linkButton"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="rightDiv">
         <img id="imgIpad" src="images/ipad.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
#outerDiv{
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    border: 0px solid;
    background-color:#e4ecfe;
}
#middleDiv{
    width: 35%;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid;
}
#leftDiv{
    margin: auto;
    width: 35%;
    float: left;
    left: -10%;
    border: 1px solid;
    text-align: center;
}
#rightDiv{
    width: 28%;
    text-align: right;
    float: left;
}
#buttonDiv{
    text-align: center;
    border:1px solid; 
    border-radius:5px; 
    color:white;    
    line-height: 140%;
    font-family: Arial;
}
```

What did I try? Like I said, I tried it with the line-height but the height is variable (depends on the size of the window). I also tried something with `#outerDiv:before` but it didn't work either.

Any suggestions?

edit:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5cT2T/

SOLUTION:

Get the height per jQuery and set the margin-top with the following code:

```
var height = $(window).height(),
    middleHeight = $("#middleDiv").height(),
    leftHeight = $("#leftDiv").height();
$('#leftDiv').css('margin-top', (height - leftHeight) / 2);
$('#middleDiv').css('margin-top', (height - middleHeight) / 2);
```

Comment: provide pls link to JSFiddle, that be better and faster to find a solution

Comment: you can try this link http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/

Comment: Just use javascript (or jQuery) to calculate the window height and adjust accordingly.

Comment: And be sure to check the name identifier. In html - `LeftDiv`, in css - `leftDiv`

Comment: Yeah I have it right on my computer.

@remus, I tried to do it but when I set the line-height, it doesn't do anything. Or do you mean to work with margin-top etc. off these numbers?

Comment: Yeah, margin-top. Or position: absolute; top: XXXX

Answer (score 0):

If you want to vertically center a div inside another one, the most common tecnique is to "position:absolute" the inner div inside the external one, setting "top:50%" for position.

Doing this, will bring the upper boundary of the inner div to 50% of external div's height, so simply add a negative "margin-top" to the inner one. The value of negative margin is equal to half of its height.

If I correctly understood what you want... simply wrap your LeftDiv and MiddleDiv inside a container, and apply the suggested tecnique between container and LeftDiv! :-)